# Token conversion with Binance API

Tags: api, binance, binance-api-client

Im looking for the Binance UI token conversion (https://www.binance.com/en/convert) equivalent API endpoint, but can't really find it in the docs. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use the [Symbol Price Ticker](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#symbol-price-ticker) which will give you current price between pairs of symbols.

For example:

```
GET https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price?symbol=BTCUSDT
```

Response:

```json
{
  "symbol": "BTCUSDT",
  "price": "28275.50000000"
}
```